# Circular ImageView with bottom-right circular colored badge

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-recyclerview, imageview

Here is the type of layout that is needed to be inflated for the RecyclerView.

[image]

I used CircleImageView library to achieve the rounded Image. (https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView)

Now my question is, how do I get another background (just a color really) to appear over it (Like the blue color part in the image above)

Here is what I've been able to achieve so far.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout` and put another imageview on that image.

Comment: @Piyush I already tried that. It looks proper in the layout but once inflated it looks disproportional. (Perhaps since I have to manually set the width and height for it to appear down there.)

Comment: If you need exactness you should create your custom view and draw on `Canvas`. Otherwise you can specify gravity and paddings, which will vary the position of small circle depending on devices' screen size.

Comment: @azizbekian It doesn't need to be exact. It just needs to be over the CircleImageView which is set at match_parent for width and height in the custom layout in the manner shown in the pic.

Comment: @sHOLE check my answer below. hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**# SOLUTION 1:**

1. Create a custom `drawable` for circular `blue` color `badge` and put this drawable `XML` file into `/res/drawable/` folder.

**circular_badge.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <solid android:color="#009DDB" />
    <stroke
        android:color="#FFFFFF"
        android:width="1.5dp" />
</shape>
```

2. Use a `CircleImageView` for showing `image` and a `View` for showing circular `blue` color `badge`.
3. Set drawable `circular_badge` to `badge` View background by using `android:background="@drawable/circular_badge"`
4. Wrap `CircleImageView` and `View` into a `RelativeLayout` to show the `blue` color `badge` on `bottom-right` position of `image`.

**Here is the working XML code:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/dummy"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/badge"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circular_badge"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

**# SOLUTION 2:**

1. Use two `CircleImageView`, one for showing `image` and another for showing circular `blue` color `badge`.
2. Wrap this two `CircleImageView` into a `RelativeLayout` to show the `blue` color `badge` on `bottom-right` position of `image`.

**Here is the working XML code:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/dummy"/>

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/badge"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:src="#009DDB"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 2):

The answers from @Ferdoum and @Aditya are correct.

But I want to expand this answer.

You can define a Custom View to implement the business.
Such as below code :

```
public class CircleOnlineLayout extends FrameLayout {
    private ImageView mProfileView;
    private ImageView mOnlineView;

    public CircleOnlineLayout(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CircleOnlineLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CircleOnlineLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        initView(context, attrs);
    }

    private void initView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.circle_online, this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();

        mProfileView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
        mOnlineView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.online_view);
    }

    public void setAvatarResource(int resource) {
        mProfileView.setImageResource(resource);
    }

    public void setOnline(boolean online) {
        mOnlineView.setImageResource(online ? R.color.online_color : R.color.offline_color);
    }
}
```

and the circle_online.xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:civ_border_color="#89000000"
        app:civ_border_width="1dp"
        />

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/online_view"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:src="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        app:civ_border_color="#FFFFFF"
        app:civ_border_width="1dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So you can use CircleOnlineLayout.setAvatarResource and CircleOnlineLayout.setOnline. Of cause, you can add other export api

Answer (score 1):

Try this way it will work

```
<FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/petdetail_img"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"

                android:src="@drawable/user" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/petdetail_camera"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:src="@drawable/cameraedit"
                />

        </FrameLayout>
```

for circulerimageview add this in your gradle.build

```
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
```

**output**

[image]